# Spring 3 Autowire Bean which uses an Interface

Tags: spring, interface, javabeans, autowired

I have an Bean configured in my dispatcher-servlet.xml. In a class i can successfully inject this bean with the autowired annotation e.g.

```
class test {
  @Autowired
  TestBean testBean;
}
```

But as soon i add an interface with the "implements" keyword to the testbean, i get an IllegalArgumentException:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.test.TestBean field com.test.myclass.testBean to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.

When in remove the "implements" keyword, including the name of the interface, all works fine again.

Comment: Can you show the class declaration for the interface and the class you are referencing? Is TestBean a class or an interface? What is the interface you are adding?

Comment: Okay i resolved the problem now. I had simply to autowire against my interface, not the class. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to provide more details, like the interface type and your context configuration, but the reason is the following. Spring, by default, uses JDK proxies to add AOP or decorator behavior, for example, for `@Transactional` or `@Async`.

JDK proxies only work with interface types, not with class types. Take this example

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Example example = new Example();
        Proxied proxy = (Proxied) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Driver.class.getClassLoader(), example.getClass().getInterfaces(), new InvocationHandler() {
            Example target = example;
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                System.out.println("intercepted");
                return method.invoke(example, args);
            }
        });

        proxy.execute();

        System.out.println(proxy.getClass());
        System.out.println(proxy.getClass().getSuperclass());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(proxy.getClass().getInterfaces()));
    }

    static class Example implements Proxied {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            System.out.println("Example executing.");
        }
    }

    static interface Proxied {
        void execute();
    }
}
```

which prints

```
intercepted
Example executing.
class com.spring.$Proxy0
class java.lang.reflect.Proxy
[interface com.spring.Driver$Proxied]
```

For the purpose of this example, Spring will take the `Example` bean (declared in a context), decide that it needs to proxy it, use the `Example` class' interfaces, and create whatever `InvocationHandler` it needs by referring to the bean as the target to invoke the method on.

What you need to take note of is that the object that is returned by `Proxy.newProxyInstance(..)` is not of type `Example`. It is of type `Proxy` and of whatever type the interfaces of `Example` are. That is why Spring cannot use the proxy object to set a field (through reflection) of type `Example`, or `TestBean` in your case.

Two ways to make it work. First, extract an interface from your class, if it doesn't have one already and use a field of the interface type.

Second, you can instead configure your context to use CGLIB proxies which can proxy by class type.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your answer. Iam testing a lot here :-) ... What do you mean with "use a field of the interface type". Are there other ways to use interfaces as with "implements". That would be new to me :-) ...

Comment: @J.Archer No, I mean instead of having `private Example example;` as a member variable, you would have `private Proxied example;`. The proxy has all the interface types of your object, but doesn't have the class type. See the output of my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

in XML:

```
<bean id="test" class="your.package.Test"/>
```

make sure Test is in your spring bean XML, you then can do

```
@Autowired
Test test;

test.testBean.doAnything();
```

thing to notice here is that you HAVE to intatiate your Test class.

Comment: Your second snippet will throw a `NullPointerException`.